# Python StackAPI error

Tags: python-2.7

I have been using the StackAPI to get some data for a class, which was working; however, yesterday I suddenly started getting an error after I re-ran the first few lines of code.  I did not register an app so I know I have a limit of 300 requests per day.  I just wanted to know if this is the error you get when that is the case or if something else is going on.

FYI, I learned my lesson and will be storing the requests into a dictionary as soon as I can get the program back up and running.

```
from stackapi import StackAPI
SITE = StackAPI('stackoverflow')
```

> .../stackapi.pyc in fetch(self, endpoint, page, key, filter, **kwargs)
>
> 197                 code = response["error_name"]
>
> 198                 message = response["error_message"]
>
> --> 199                 raise StackAPIError(self._previous_call, error, code, message)
>
> 200             except KeyError:
>
> 201                 pass  # This means there is no error
>
> StackAPIError:

**Update:**

It was an issue with too many requests; however, the error handler didn't appear to be sending me the message.

```
ipdb> print error
502

ipdb> print code
throttle_violation

ipdb> print message
too many requests from this IP, more requests available in 16818 seconds
```

Comment: Why not catch the exception and see what the attributes on it are?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder.  I should have guessed the error handler was the problem and not the error itself.  I'll update the code to show what should have been passed.